# How to add a form element to Symfony Form after error

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I have a symfony2 form.

What I want to do is if there is an error, add a captcha field to the form, so for the second time, that also needs to be filled out. The captcha is not the important question here, but how to add that field after submission and how do I know it was submitted if the from can't be changed after submission?

So the main question, how can I add a text input field if there was an error?

Comment: Use form events to add fields after submission: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/form/form_events.html

Comment: Thanks, but as I wrote, I need it only after the first error. If I use simply events, if will be there at the first call.

Comment: Forms are completely rebuilt upon each submission.  If no error then process the data and redirect.  If there is an error, add the captcha field and display the form again.  You will probably need to set a flag so your form template only trys to display the captcha field if it exists.  You might be making this harder than it is.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('foo', 'number')
        ->add('bar', 'number')
        ->add('submit', 'submit')
    ;

    $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, [$this, 'onPreSubmit']);
}

public function onPreSubmit(FormEvent $event)
{
    if (!$event->getForm()->isValid()) {
        $event->getForm()->add('test', 'text', [
            'mapped' => false
        ]);
    }

}
```

Comment: Well, this is not working :) As after submit the form is not editable :) So the answer is not as easy as you suggests. And YES, I spent nearly half a day and I'm not new to symfony.